# MonoDroid - How to use DialogPreference?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a DialogPreference by subclassing the DialogPreference class and declaring it in my preferences xml file.

When I call the AddPreferencesFromResource in my PreferenceActivity I get a System.NotSupportedException. I cannot catch this exception to copy it so I have a couple of screen shots below of what it looks like when the exception is thrown.

I have copied and coverted the code for the DialogPreference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen).

How can this be implemented in Mono for Android?

This is my xml for the DialogPreference:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Opening Odds">
    <app.monodroid.TimePickerPreference
     android:key="openoddstime"
     android:title="Opening Odds Time"
     android:dialogMessage="Time of day to get the opening odds."
     android:defaultValue="">
    </app.monodroid.TimePickerPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that you ate missing the constructor that takes two arguments, `IntPtr` and `Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership`. 
I think you have to override the base constructor of all wrappers.