# Android preferences text size

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using time picker class from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10608622/1261256

On preference screen, I have several options (e.g. ringtone) in addition to 'Time', which is tied to the above time picker class.

However, the text for 'Time' is larger than the text for the other preferences. How can I make it uniform?

This is settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="notification" />

<com.xxxx.TimePreference
    android:key="notification_time"
    android:dependency="notification"
    android:title="@string/pref_notification_time" />

<RingtonePreference
    android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
    android:dependency="notification"
    android:key="notification_ringtone"
    android:ringtoneType="notification"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_ringtone" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Above xml file gets added using:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this too.

The `TimePreference` class, in its 2 parameter constructor, calls the 3 parameter constructor with `0` for the third parameter, which uses the default style.  Since this is a Preference class, it should call it with `android.R.attr.preferenceStyle` as the third parameter to use the preference style.  Make a change to the code so the two parameter constructor looks like this:

```
    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(ctxt, attrs, android.R.attr.preferenceStyle);
    }
```