# Android Preference up down list dialog

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

How to make the up down list of the preference dialog below? Is it a ListPreference? How to populate the arrays.xml with a range of integer?

[image]

Comment: it is a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html). [This Link](https://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/) may be helpful.

Comment: Is some of us is answers solved your problem? @Ming Leung

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a custom `DialogPreference`, using a `NumberPicker` as its content.

See:

- [Android PreferenceActivity dialog with number picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758986/android-preferenceactivity-dialog-with-number-picker)
- https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/959884
- https://gist.github.com/lukehorvat/4398028

for various implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You need custom dialog for this action. Create a layout for your custom dialog and you use `NumberPicker` class for that. You can check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17944205/4376058