# Cannot load default values from custom preference

Tags: android, preference

I used Mark Murphy's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen) to built a custom preference, a TimePreference with a TimePicker in particular. I have a problem with getting and storing the default values in onSetInitialValue method, where null is returned. I also read that `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);` does not work with strings, which in fact does not work in my case. Is there a way to get and set the default values without using the PreferenceManager's getDefaultSharedPreferences method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the preference file from the emulator and everything is back to normal