# PreferenceManager cannot load default value of custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I used code sample for TimePreference from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen).
Related to my question methods:

```
@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    Log.v(TAG, "a.getString(index):  " + a.getString(index));
    Log.v(TAG, "hasKey(): " + hasKey() );
    return a.getString(index);
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    String time=null;

    if (restoreValue) {
        if (defaultValue==null) {
            time=getPersistedString(DEFAULT_NOTIF_TIME_STRING);
        }
        else {
            time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
        }
    }
    else {
        time=defaultValue.toString();
    }

    lastHour=getHour(time);
    lastMinute=getMinute(time);
}
```

In notification_time_fragment.xml:

```
<mypackage.preferences.TimePreference
    android:key ="@string/notif_time_key"
    android:title="@string/notif_time_title"
    android:defaultValue="08:00"
    android:persistent="true"
    />
```

In activity

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.notification_time_fragment, true);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String notificationTime = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.notif_time_key), "can't read time");
```

And notificationTime is equal to "can't read time". 
Logging from onGetDefaultValue:

```
a.getString(index):  08:00
hasKey(): false
```

I guess that this `false` from `hasKey()` is the reason why the preference is not saved in `sharedPreference` by command `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()`.

I must say that `android:defaultValue` of `EditTextPreference, CheckBoxPreference`  are properly retrieved from xml-resource using the same  commands.

Why `hasKey()` is `false`?
What is wrong in TimePreference? How can I make it to write its default value without launching `PreferenceActivity` and without "dirty coding" in `MainActivity`?

Comment: log `hasKey()` inside `TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor after calling `super`

Comment: hasKey() from constructor: true

Comment: is `onSetInitialValue` ever called? if so, try to debug it step by step

Comment: Constructor log is later than log from onGetDefaultValue. Is it OK?

Comment: yes, it is OK, see the Preference.java sources

Comment: onSetInitialValue is called after onGetDefaultValue and constructor

Comment: did you debug it step by step?

Comment: Right now i can't. I'll do it later.