# Change color onTimePicker

Tags: android, xml, styles, timepicker

In my app there is a TimePicker on PreferenceFragment. Implementation of it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533295/3499878

So my result in image:

[image]

I want to change gray color(#555555) to more light color.

In my style I used:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyDialog</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#2962ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2962ff</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

So `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` as in `MyTheme`, as in `Theme.Dialog` not work for it purpose `ColorPrimary` in `Theme.MyDialog` for text header ("StartTime"), and button "Cancel", "OK". `ColorAccent` in `MyTheme` used only for selected time in circle.
How to resolve it problem?

Comment: How do you use the `WaterTheme`?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. Instead WaterTheme must be MyTheme. It's theme of my application in manifest
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>

Comment: @shhp With MyTheme result same. Color doesn't change.

Comment: Try deleting the `android:` prefix in `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyDialog</item>`.