# How to delete an AndroidX Preference value?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, androidx

I created a custom [`Preference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.html) `RangeBarPreference`. I must have initially persisted the preference value as an `Integer` as I'm getting this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

when trying to perform [`persistString("text")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.html#persistString(java.lang.String)).

`persistString()` works fine when I change my preference `key` from `age_range` to something different:

```
<app.meeq.RangeBarPreference
    android:key="minmax_age"
    android:title="Age Range"
    android:layout="@layout/preference_rangebar"/>
```

but I would like to use the initial key `age_range`, even though it's saved as an `Int/Integer`.

How can I delete the `age_range` `Preference` value so I can use `persistString()` on it?

Comment: uninstall your app to clear the keys if the problem is change the key to another type. but if you want to have same key for different type at runtime then check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I did uninstall and reinstall but the key is still there unfortunately

Comment: try it on other device or emulator just make sure of the problem.