# Kotlin - type mismatch with generic return type and subclass

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, android-jetpack

I hope everybody is staying healthy amid this pandemic :)

I could use some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong here, TIA! Also, I'm a little new to Kotlin so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to extend a class and implement an interface that are defined in a java library (AndroidX). However, when I try to implement the interface function I get a type mismatch error with my return value. Since I'm using an interface defined in the AndroidX library, simply changing the interface function signature to make it build is not an option.

I'm basically converting this other SO answer to Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398747/535638

Dev machine/IDE info:
Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 26, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.services.firebase

I tried to generalize this error with the code below, to hopefully save you some effort in grokking the other SO question, and I'm getting the same compiler error with this generalized code.

```
open class LibraryClassA {

}

open class LibraryClassB {
    val retval = LibraryClassA()

    // this kotlin signature seems to be inferred/transcribed from java by the IDE/compiler
    open fun <T : LibraryClassA?> foobar(): T? {
        return null
    }
}

class MyClass : LibraryClassB() {

    override fun <T : LibraryClassA?> foobar(): T? {
        return retval // compiler error on this line - type mismatch, Required T?, Found LibraryClassA
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this was a dumb question... I was able to cast to T `return retval as T` which created an unchecked cast warning, but it seems to be functioning correctly. I'm not sure why the kotlin compiler can't handle this case without the explicit cast. Also not sure how much sense it makes to cast to a generic type, so I'm hoping somebody more knowledgeable in kotlin can speak to that. I'll give it some time and post this as the answer later if nobody else replies.

Comment: "this kotlin signature seems to be inferred/transcribed from java" From which part? I don't see anything similar in the linked answer.

Comment: I meant that to say the kotlin compiler is generating that as the signature to override, which is an interface that looks to me to be written in java in the androidx library. when I override that java function in kotlin, that is what is automatically generated for me.

Comment: Please point to the specific interface so we can see its documentation and how it is intended to be used.

Comment: sure thing - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference.TargetFragment and https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer explains the why behind the compiler error, but since I cannot modify the library I'm using easily, the solution to my problem was to do a cast and suppress the warning.

My final code looks like this:

```
override fun <T : Preference?> findPreference(key: CharSequence): T? {

    // unchecked cast needed since we can't modify the library code to call this with the
    // correct type parameter, and we can't modify the function signature
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return this.preference as T
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fundamental issue.

When you write

```
fun <T : LibraryClassA?> foobar(): T? { ... }
```

you are declaring that *the caller* of `foobar` can specify any subclass of `LibraryClassA` that they want, and get an instance of *that*.  For example, if there were

```
class FooClass : LibraryClassA() { ... }
```

someone could call

```
val myFooClass: FooClass = myLibraryClassB.foobar<FooClass>()
```

and expect that to work.  What you have will *not* work for that, because what you will have will be a `LibraryClassA` instance, *not* a `FooClass` instance.

If the intention is that you are returning *some* subclass of `LibraryClassA?`, but that the implementation of `LibraryClassB` controls what they get, not the caller, then the correct type of that function is

```
fun foobar(): LibraryClassA? { ... }
```

Comment: I cannot speak to the intention of the interface since I'm not the author (it is defined in the androidx library), but my guess is that it is a locator function to get the class member which is-a LibraryClassA