# TimePicker - how to get AM or PM?

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to set an alarm based on a user's selection in TimePicker. TimePicker is set to AM/PM mode. In order to know if a user wants his alarm to set to 10 AM or 10 PM, how should I get the AM/PM value?

The listener `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` passes only hours and minutes.

Answer (score 36):

Above answers are right i found simplest way to find AM PM.

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onStartTimeListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String AM_PM ;
        if(hourOfDay < 12) {
            AM_PM = "AM";
        } else {
            AM_PM = "PM";
        }

        mStartTime.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute + " " + AM_PM );
    }
};
```

Comment: If the time format is in 24hours, why do we need AM_PM? Is there any other way to get AM_PM in 12 hours format?

Answer (score 22):

On callback from

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
```

call below function

```
private String getTime(int hr,int min) {
        Time tme = new Time(hr,min,0);//seconds by default set to zero
        Format formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        return formatter.format(tme);
    }
```

The functions return something like this 1:12 PM

Comment: Time class is deprecated, please use code below to formate the time


`SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a",Locale.getDefault());

Calenter calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.setCurrentMinutes());
calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);

timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime);`

Answer (score 12):

You can get AM/PM from Timepicker using following method.
Timepicker is a viewgroup.That's why we can get its child view index 2 which demonstrates AM/PM is actually a button. So we can get its text.

```
 Mycallback=new OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup) view.getChildAt(0);
            Toast.makeText(TimePickerDemoActivity.this, hourOfDay+":"+minute+":"+((Button)vg.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString(), 5000).show();

        }
    };
```

Comment: It's not a proper way. It works on 2.2 but doesn't work on 4.1

Comment: I used another approach. I've posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I would've preferred to leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. By far the most succinct way to get AM or PM is using the ternary operator:

```
String am_pm = (hourOfDay < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
```

Comment: but what should one do if you are in am-pm mode... is24HourView() returns false. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#is24HourView()

Comment: [Same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm/2660148#2660148)

Answer (score 5):

I did it using Calendar, and that should work on all versions:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
    String am_pm = "";

    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        am_pm = "PM";

    String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":Integer.toString( datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) );


    ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnEventStartTime)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );
}
```

Notice the use of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and `Calendar.HOUR` if you go to the documentation of both you'd know the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Here I'm taking the current date and time from the system and updating it with date and time picker dialog

```
private int  mMonth,mYear,mDay,mHour,mMin;

public static final int DTPKR = 1;

public static final int TMPKR = 2;

// Getting  the current date and time into DatePicker dialog

    public void getCurrentDate(){
       final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    } 

    public void getCurrentTime(){
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

      }
```

Now create the dialogs and update the values 
//Creating  dialogs

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DTPKR:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,lisDate, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        case TMPKR:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,lisTime,mHour, mMin, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //setting date and updating editText 

       DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener lisDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                 int dayOfMonth) {
                   mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                etDate.setText(new StringBuilder() .append(mDay).append("/").append(mMonth+1).append("/").append(mYear));
                getCurrentDate();     

             }
    };

  //setting time and updating editText 

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener lisTime=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour=hourOfDay;
            mMin=minute;

             String AM_PM ;
                if(hourOfDay < 12) {
                    AM_PM = "AM";

                } else {
                    AM_PM = "PM";
                    mHour=mHour-12;
                }
                etTime.setText(mHour+":"+mMin+" "+AM_PM);
                getCurrentDate();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it'll help but I am kind of working on the same thing. See my reply here
[TimePickerDialog and AM or PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm)

Answer (score 1):

I think callback will be called with hour in 24-format because. Dialog uses `TimePicker` internally. And `TimePicker` has [getCurrentHour](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentHour%28%29) moethod, which returns hour in 0-23 format.

Answer (score 0):

e.g :

```
TimePicker sellerTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.sellerTime);

Integer.toString(((sellerTime.getCurrentHour().intValue()) > 12) ?  ((sellerTime.getCurrentHour().intValue()) - 12) : 
(sellerTime.getCurrentHour().intValue())
```