# timepicker:- how to get am and pm displayed?

Tags: java, android

My app has timepicker to select time im able to get hours and minutes,
which is then sent through a sms programmatically,
Im able to send the hours and minutes using

getCurrentHour()

getCurrentMinute()

How do i get the Am and Pm from the timepicker?
is it possible?
im not using dialog,directly using timepicker

I want the time to be in this format eg. 4:30PM

Answer (score 2):

The `hourOfDay` will always be `24-hour`. If you opened the `dialog` with `is24HourView` set to `false`, the user will not have to deal with `24-hour` formatted times, but Android will convert that to a `24-hour` time when it calls `onTimeSet()`.

Source :- 1) [How to get AM/PM from time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660148/519718)

2) [second way of doing the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11795693/519718)

You can always convert 24 hour format to 12 hour format do something like below

```
String s = "12:18:00";
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date d = f1.parse(s);
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
f2.format(d).toLowerCase(); // "12:18am"
```

go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doc also

Comment: but i want the message to be displayed eg. 4:30 PM