# Get time using time picker android

Tags: android, timepicker

How can I simply get time, set by the user on time picker widget in android ?

Like this.

```
timepicker.gettime();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to get the time from a TimePicker when it is typed in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992820/android-how-to-get-the-time-from-a-timepicker-when-it-is-typed-in)

Comment: timepicker.clearfocus() solved my problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try it like below.

## Java

For picking hour you can use

```
timePicker.getCurrentHour();
```

and for picking minutes you can use

```
timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

and then you can set this hour and minute to any Integer variable. Like

```
int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

## Kotlin

For picking hour you can use

```
timePicker.hour;
```

and for picking minutes you can use

```
timePicker.minute;
```

and then you can set this hour and minute to any Integer variable. Like

```
int hour = timePicker.hour;
int minute = timePicker.minute;
```

for more information you can refer to this link

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

Answer (score 12):

If you are using below API 23. then you can use

```
int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

And after 23 you can use both

```
int hour = timePicker.getHour();
int minute = timePicker.getMinute();
```